# Modify child element when other child is fired

Tags: javascript, parent-child

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a href=''></a>
</div>

<div class='wrap'>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a href=''></a>
</div>

<div class='wrap'>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a href=''></a>
</div>
```

I had a lot of parent elements with same children content.
When an event is fired to a child, do something with the other child of the same  parent.

For example:

```
< textarea > onkeyup (from parent A) change the background-color of < a > (from parent A)
```

How to deal with this?

Comment: So, what have you tried and why it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for either [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) (applied to `$(this)` within an event handler), or possibly a combination of [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) and [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) (if the other element may be at a different level, which isn't the case in your example).

Example - `siblings`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/EpiriSe/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/EpiriSe/1/edit)

```
$(".wrap textarea").on("keyup", function() {
    var link = $(this).siblings("a");
    link.css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Example - `closest` + `find`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/EpiriSe/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/EpiriSe/2/edit)

```
$(".wrap textarea").on("keyup", function() {
    var link = $(this).closest(".wrap").find("a");
    link.css("background-color", "green");
});
```

Comment: the first one didn't worked for me but the 2nd one (closest + find) does. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IvorySantos: They both work with the markup in the question (see the live examples I've added). As I said in the answer, `siblings` will only work with elements at the same level (siblings of the element on which the event fired). Glad that helped.

Comment: @T.JCrowder I'm curious that's why I've tried to use the siblings again. But I can't make it work. I don't know what's wrong. Maybe some of my existing  codes make this function faulty. Thanks

Comment: @IvorySantos: Most likely, the elements you're selecting aren't siblings of the element on which the event fires. For instance: `<div class="wrap"><textarea></textarea><p><a href=''>...</a></p></div>` There, the `a` element is not a sibling of the `textarea`.